# using Guava Multimap to represent xml names and values

Tags: java, collections, guava

How can I use Guava Multimap to represent the following xml:

```
<node key="abc123">some value</node>
<node key="asdf22">
   <node key="as234">some value343</node>
   <node key="sggg234">some value234234</node>
</node>
```

In my xml files, 90% of the time a given node element will not have inner nodes (in case I can optimize for that?).

What I wanted was a KeyValuePair collection, where the value is another collection of keyValuePairs.

In c# I could do:

```
public List<string,List<KeyValuePair<string,string>>> nodes;
```

I was told to look at Guava's multimap, but not sure how to use it correctly, can someone help me out?

BTW, since 90% of the cases I don't need the value to be another List, could I somehow optimize for this situation?

Comment: You're trying to represent two different datatypes, either a string, or a collection of nodes. Normal XML parsers would use a text node for the inner text; you can create a map identical to the C# example you show, but how would you store the first node that has only text in it? Unless you have a special value (`null`?) for when there's no nodes, the structure shown doesn't immediately make sense to me.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure the MultiMap is a best fit for what you've described here. A multimap is where you have multiple values for the same key. That's not what your XML describes. Your XML describes a hierarchy where each value has a path, possibly with multiple keys concatenated to describe it's location within the hierarchy.

From a modeling standpoint, I'd consider going with 2 types of XML nodes. 1 holds values, and the other holds nodes (think Files vs Directories). You'll need to switch up your XML though to make a clear delineation between the two different types. It'll be easier to parse that way.

So, in rough psuedo code..

```
class Container {
  private Map<String,String> keyValuePairs;
  private Map<String,Container> children;
}
```

This gives you infinite depth. Each container can hold keyValue pairs as well as other containers. Top level node should be the root container. Recursion should be trivial. Traversal by key/separator should also be easy.

Possibly more flexible than you need. Trim as necessary.

You could also merge the concept of the values/containers, but then your modeling gets a bit uglier. It's a tradeoff.

Comment: I don't have control over the xml.

Comment: That's unfortunate, but not a show stopper. It just makes parsing a touch more complicated, but still doable.